# Convert pyBarcode output to PIL Image file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert the output of pyBarcode to a PIL Image file without first saving an image.  First off, pyBarcode generates an image file like such:

```
>>> import barcode
>>> from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
>>> ean = barcode.get_barcode('ean', '123456789102', writer=ImageWriter())
>>> filename = ean.save('ean13')
>>> filename
u'ean13.png'
```

As you can see above, I don't want the image to be actually saved on my filesystem because I want the output to be processed into a PIL Image.  So I did some modifications:

```
i = StringIO()
ean = barcode.get_barcode('ean', '123456789102', writer=ImageWriter())
ean.write(i)
```

Now I have a StringIO file object and I want to PIL to "read" it and convert it to a PIL Image file.  I wanted to use `Image.new` or `Image.frombuffer` but both these functions required me to enter a size...can't the size be determined from the barcode StringIO data?  `Image.open` states this in their documentation:

> You can use either a string (representing the filename) or a file object.  In the latter case, the file object must implement read, seek and tell methods, and be opened in binary mode

Isn't a StringIO instance a file object as well?  How do I open it as a binary file?

```
Image.open(i, 'rb')
>>> Image.open(i, 'rb')                                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                            
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                  
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/barcode/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1947, in open                                                                                                                     
    raise ValueError("bad mode")                                                                                 
ValueError: bad mode
```

I'm sure I'm pretty close to the answer I just need someone's guidance.  Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have you tried to omit the second parameter from `Image.open` (I mean, just open it in the default mode)?

Comment: Did you `.seek(0)` to return to the beginning of the the `StringIO`?. Then, as PauloScardine suggested, omit the second parameter. Might want to try using `io.BytesIO` too.

Comment: Thanks guys!  The seek(0) and omitting the second parameter did the trick!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StringIO` objects *are* file objects.

However, if you are using the [`cStringIO` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) (the C-optimized version of the `StringIO` module) then do note that once you ceate an empty`StringIO` instance, it is optimized for writing only, and you cannot use it as in input file, and vice-versa. Simply reinitialize it in that case:

```
i = StringIO(i.getvalue())  # create a cStringIO.StringO instance for a cStringIO.StringI instance.
```

For the python version (the `StringIO` module), simply seek to the start again:

```
i.seek(0)
```

You do *not* need to specify a file mode for the `Image.open()` call; unless `i` is a string it'll be ignored in any case:

```
img = Image.open(i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  The i.seek(0) did the trick.  Though I don't really understand what you mean by reinitialize the StringIO(i.getvalue())

Comment: @Mark: `from cStringIO import StringIO`, then `StringIO('somevalue')` creates an output (read-only) object, while `StringIO()` creates an input object (write-only). So to switch from writing to reading, you have to create the first type from the latter.

Comment: Ah!! I get it.  You mean if I provide an argument, the output would be read-only, where as if I were to omit the argument, the output would be write-only.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Mark: Exactly. It's something many users of the `cStringIO` module run into.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me to convert the output to a PIL image file:

```
import barcode
ean = barcode.get('ean13', '123456789102', writer = barcode.writer.ImageWriter())
image = ean.render()
```

This way does not require StringIO

Comment: Don't know why this isn't marked as the correct answer. Its simple and gives a ```<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>``` image to edit as needed.  Great!

Comment: Much better solution